# c# cast error (infinte value....what?)

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, dataset

Prob something im overlooking but this problem has annoyed me greatly.
im trying to get a value from a dataset and then use it to do some calculations.
in the dataset its seen as an object, so i need to cast it to an int or double.
For some reason im getting a stupid error thats getting on my nerves. heres the code.

```
private void SpendsAnalysis()
    {
        float tempQty = 0;
        float tempPrice = 0;
        double tempTot = 0;
        double total = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            tempQty = (float)row.Cells["Qty"].Value;
            tempPrice = (float)row.Cells["Unit"].Value;

            tempTot = tempQty * tempPrice;
            total += tempTot;
        }

        textBox7.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

Thrown: "Specified cast is not valid." (System.InvalidCastException)
when casting form a number, must be less than inifnite.   This is the annoying error im getting.  now i get the data from my dataset, which gets its data from a stored procedure.
I believe the "Qty" field type is currency(yeh, why is qty currency haha, not my tables!).  in my datagrid view it looks like 1.000, is this due to a type conversion? how would i rectify this?
Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `float` is certainly a worse match than `currency` or `decimal`. But you sound like it should be an integer. Any `float`/`double` occurring in a monetary calculation is a big red flag.

Comment: agree but these are values set by the original table.  im casting it to a value i can work with, ither double or float

Comment: And why not `Decimal`? You can use decimal in C#, and it's certainly a better choice than either `float` or `double` here.

Comment: what about using decimal? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A type cast has to succeed, and unfortunately, casting directly from an `object` to a different type than the underlying object is not going to work, even if casting from a `decimal` (the .NET type for `currency`) to a `float` would normally work.

If the type in the database is `currency`, I would try this:

```
= (float)(decimal)row.Cells["Qty"].Value;
```

or, you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle.aspx):

```
= Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells["Qty"].Value);
```

which will take a look at the actual value and figure out the right type of conversion to perform.

To answer your comment, the above expression involves two distinct conversions:

- An unboxing conversion from `object` to a value-type, in this case to a `decimal`
- An explicit conversion from `decimal` to `float`

The first, the unboxing conversion, is documented in the C# language specification section 4.3.2 (this is the [C# 4.0 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029)):

> An unboxing operation to a non-nullable-value-type **consists of first checking that the object instance is a boxed value of the given non-nullable-value-type**, and then copying the value out of the instance.

*(my emphasis)*

I also have the annotated version of the specification, and Eric Lippert summarizes this as:

> Although it is legal to convert an unboxed int to an unboxed double, it is not legal to convert a boxed int to an unboxed double—only to an unboxed int.

The second, the explicit conversion, is documented in the C# language specification section 6.2.1:

> **6.2.1 Explicit Numeric Conversions**
>   The explicit numeric conversions are the conversions from a numeric-type to another numeric-type for which an implicit numeric conversion (§6.1.2) does not already exist:
>   ...
>   From **decimal** to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, **float**, or  double.

*(again, my emphasis)*

To summarize:

- When "casting" from an `object` to a value-type, you're actually unboxing the boxed value, and you first have to unbox the actual underlying value into its correct type, before you can convert it to a different type.

Comment: ah many thanks the convert.tosingle works a treat, so it the fact its an object that means it cannot convert?  is there anymore info on this?

Comment: Having said all I wanted to say in my answer, are you sure you *want* it as a `float` and not as a `decimal`?

Comment: yeh changed to decimal now, very nice explanation. ty very much!